# Setting AWS S3 Region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to create an aws s3 bucket using the following java code.

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
```

But I am getting the following error:

"exception": "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException",
    "message": "Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region."

Am I trying to set region in an incorrect way? Please advice.

Comment: simply pass "ap-south-1" as a String.

Comment: Actually, I have to set this as property in a config file after installing AWS CLI.Though the region is now getting picked up, I am getting a different error which states 400 Bad Request.

Comment: If you are using the aws cli make sure the user has permission to create the bucket and if the bucket name matches the requirements as mentioned below :The bucket name can be between 3 and 63 characters long, and can contain only lower-case characters, numbers, periods, and dashes.

Each label in the bucket name must start with a lowercase letter or number.

The bucket name cannot contain underscores, end with a dash, have consecutive periods, or use dashes adjacent to periods.

The bucket name cannot be formatted as an IP address (198.51.100.24).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any proxies and you already setup your credentials, you can use below code:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
.withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
```

But if you need to setup a proxy and manually set the credentials, you can use below code:

```
AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(<accessKey>,<secretKey>);
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred))
.withClientConfiguration(<your configuration>)
.withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is you have not setup AWS with Eclipse.

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE then read:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/welcome.html

Once the profile is setup then

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

Region apSouth1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1);

s3.setRegion(apSouth1);

Also make sure to import:

import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

Comment: Actually, I did setup AWS with eclipse.The credentials are set in both .aws/config file and in environment variables too.The region and credentials are getting picked as I can see during debugging, but still, I get 400 Bad request error.

Comment: In your case since you are creating  s3 bucket - 400 Bad request error means InvalidBucketName - The specified bucket is not valid.         
Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long.
Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels are separated by a single period (.).                                                  
Bucket names can contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must start and end with a lowercase letter or a number.
Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (e.g., 192.168.5.4).