# How can we use OVH s3 api to access ovh cloud storage in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, storage, ovh

I want to use ovh s3 api to access ovh cloud storage in java using keystore, secret key , consumer key and region.
So using that i can upload files on ovh cloud storage .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using Java to connect to your backend I suggest you validate your connection with the CLI client like following

- Get your tokens you will need to generated them as explained in this documentation : https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/storage/getting_started_with_the_swift_S3_API/

  Important steps are :

  1. Source your `openrc` file

  ```
  user@host:~$ source <user_name>-openrc.sh
  ```

  2. create your `ec2` credentials
     You will get a block with it as a response from this call

  ```
  user@host:~$ openstack ec2 credentials create
  ```

  3. edit your aws credentials
     **be sure to provide the region and correct links to OVHcloud storage**

  ```
  user@host:~$ cat ~/.aws/credentials

  [default]
  aws_access_key_id = <access_key>
  aws_secret_access_key = <secret_key>

  user@host:~$ cat ~/.aws/config

  [plugins]
  endpoint = awscli_plugin_endpoint

  [profile default]
  region = <region>
  s3 =
    endpoint_url = https://s3.<region>.cloud.ovh.net
    signature_version = s3v4
  s3api =
    endpoint_url = https://s3.<region>.cloud.ovh.net
  ```
- Validate the connectivity of your bucket by listing your OVHcloud storage objects.

  ```
  aws --profile default s3 ls
  ```

Then you can connect from java code you can use the code sample from this post answer [Setting AWS S3 Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586462/setting-aws-s3-region)

```
AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(<accessKey>,<secretKey>);
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred))
.withClientConfiguration(<your configuration>)
.withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
```

**Important thing is to provide the endpoint/region because sdk defaults to `US_WEST` region**